# What is the Android version of of HTML’s TextArea?

Tags: android

What is the view element in Android which gives an effect like an HTML textarea input widget?

I want to create a form to send Email and for the body field I want to create a textarea type of UI element in the form.

Can someone suggest the way to do this?

Answer (score 11):

[`EditText`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EditText.html) would seem to be the obvious choice here.

You'll need to set the [`android:inputType` attribute](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:inputType) to `textMultiLine`.